# Async and non blocking concepts in java. Is it possible to be asynchronous and blocking together?

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, language-agnostic, nonblocking

Before introducing with nio I thought that non-blocking and async concepts are same.

But if in `nio` it explicitly separates I think that it is different things. And now I really don't understand difference. I have read a lot of information about it but this information confuses me.

example:

`asynchronous` - tag description on stackoverflow:

> Asynchronous programming is simply allowing some portions of code to
>   be executed on separate threads. It makes your applications perform
>   better, be more responsive, and use the resources of the system they
>   are running on to the fullest extent.

Has this concept meaning without concurrency and multithreading?

In some another places I have found that threads and async is unrelated things - my brain is bump

`nonblocking` tag on SO has another menaning than I ask I suppose(but I am not sure).

> Use of concurrency without the usual mutual exclusion primitives,
>   guaranteeing that thread operations will not block indefinitely. This
>   is usually handled with atomic value modification
>   (increment/decrement) and/or reading (compare-and-exchange) operations

Please provide simple example of non-blocking and async concepts in java. And explain differences.

### P.S.

Does `synchronously` and `single-threaded` same?

please provide examples of

1. synchronous and blocking
2. synchronous and non-blocking
3. asynchronous and blocking
4. asynchronous and non-blocking

Comment: Where does NIO state that non-blocking and asych are two different things?

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078654/java-se/five-ways-to-maximize-java-nio-and-nio-2.html  for example

Comment: and this presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/BalamuruganSoundararajan/nio-and-nio2

Comment: @markspace It 'says it' in the fact that `SocketChannel` and `AsynchronousSocketChannel` both exist. Non-blocking I/O was introduced with NIO in 1.4 and asynchronous I/O with NIO2 in 1.6. They aren't the same thing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way.

**Asynchronous is a way to accomplish something while non-blocking is a property of the way you're accomplishing something.**

By nature, Asynchronous is non-blocking but it is possible to obtain non-blocking behaviour while being synchronous.

#### Synchronous and Blocking

[ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) - When you call the `accept()` method, the thread blocks and wait until someone connects to the server socket. You cannot execute anything until someone connects.

#### Synchronous and Non-Blocking

[SocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) - When configured in non-blocking mode (`configureBlocking()`), you have to use a `while(true)` along with a selector to listen on the Socket. However, the thread will almost never block(See comments) and wait until someone connects or write to the socket, it will simply keep looping in the while true until something happens.

This allows you for example to read and write at the same time, since you won't be stuck in blocking state by listening to the socket (Like `ServerSocket` `accept()`)

You can find a code example here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/server-socket-channel.html

#### Asynchronous and Non-Blocking

[Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) - Remember how `ServerSocket` would block on `accept()`? One way to circumvent this would be to do the operation on another `Thread`. That way it'll still be blocking, but on another thread.

So technically, it is still blocking, but since it's blocking on another thread, the main thread doesn't see any impact and continues functioning.

#### Asynchronous and Blocking

Sometimes however, we want to wait after another thread to be done before moving forward. There's multiple ways to achieve Thread Synchronization (Mutex, Infinite Loops, synchronized keyword, etc...) and it varies a lot depending on the use case.

Comment: Asynchronous channels in Java don't use threads. They use asynchronous operating system calls.

Comment: Thanks @EJP, is there any other info that you'd argue is wrong in my post?

Comment: Well you say the thread will never block in non-blocking mode. It will block in `select(),` but nowhere else.

Comment: You're right, it'll block if there is nothing to return (No operations pendings)

Comment: @PeekaySwitch Does WatchService example of synchronous and non-blocking ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, asynchronous just means "without synchronization."  That could be anything at all, and it doesn't have to involve threads or concurrency.

For example, a network packet arrives at your network port asynchronously, whether you use multi-threading or not.  ANY external event to your program is probably asynchronous.

Non-blocking just means without blocking a thread.  Besides IO (and NIO), the Java `synchronized` keyword may cause a thread to block on a memory location, regardless of any IO.  Check out the [docs of the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)

> This implementation employs an efficient "wait-free" algorithm based
>   on one described in Simple, Fast, and Practical Non-Blocking and
>   Blocking Concurrent Queue Algorithms by Maged M. Michael and Michael
>   L. Scott.

So blocking refers to your threads stopping and waiting, and that's unrelated (in general) to the concept of two or more events happening without some sort of synchronizing.

These concepts aren't just related to Java.  They're general concepts used by all systems that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thus synchronized is word related with blocking and unrelated with asyncronous???

Answer (score -3):

> Is it possible to be asynchronous and blocking together?

No. The question doesn't make sense.

There are two types of synchronous I/O: blocking and non-blocking. What they have in common is that the operation is complete when the method returns: there is no further action. (It may complete with an error of course, or do nothing). This is the meaning of 'synchronous' in this context.

In asynchronous I/O by contrast, the operation has only begun when the method returns, and completion is signalled to the code later, via a callback, or interrogating a handle.

> Please provide simple example of non-blocking and async concepts in java. And explain differences.

This is not a homework site.